# JRuby 1.5.5 keeps throwing jruby: unknown option --disable-gems

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails

After a clean install of jRuby 1.5.5, I cannot run jruby -v from the command line without getting the following error:

jruby: unknown option --disable-gems

I didn't specify that option so I don't know where it's coming from.

This also precludes me from using jruby in Netbeans.

Any ideas?

-Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was completely my oversight. I had added the --disable-gems as an environment variable in an attempt to speed up rails on a windows machine. I completely forgot.